# Using Moq, System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy' to type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Can someone help me to fix this error message please? I don't understand why the cast doesn't work:

> Message: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>   'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy' to type
>   'Automation.Pages.ToolbarElements.ElementsWithActiveState.ActiveStateElements'.

**Here is my test:**

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("unit")]
class ActiveStateElementBehaviorTests
{
    [Test]
    public void GetCurrentElementState_StateIsActive_ReturnActive()
    {
        var moqElement = new Mock<IActiveState>();
        moqElement.Setup(x => x.IsElementInActiveState()).Returns(() => true);

        var behavior = new ActiveStateElementBehavior(moqElement.Object);
        behavior.GetCurrentElementState().Should().BeEquivalentTo(ElementState.Active);
    }
}
```

**Here is my code:**

```
public class ActiveStateElementBehavior : IElementStateBehavior
{
    public ActiveStateElementBehavior(IActiveState toolbarElement)
    {
        Element = (ActiveStateElements)toolbarElement;
    }

    public ENAEPToolbarElement Element { get; }

    public ElementState GetCurrentElementState()
    {
        var element = (ActiveStateElements) Element;
        return element.IsElementInActiveState() ? ElementState.Active :
             element.IsButtonInEnabledState() ? ElementState.Default : 
             ElementState.Disabled;
    }
}

public interface IActiveState
{
    bool IsElementInActiveState();
}
```

Comment: This demonstrates what happens when you violate **Explicit Dependency Principle**. It is bad design to ask for an interface only to cast it back to an implementation concern.

Comment: The constructor is thus lying about what the class truly dependent on.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should pass in the concrete type ActiveStateElements into the constructor instead?

Comment: No, Classes should depend on abstraction and not on concretions and implementation concerns. Create an interface that will provide the necessary functionality and have the derived classes encapsulate the desired functionality.

Comment: Why are you casting to `ActiveStateElements` in the first place.

Comment: Because Element.IsElementInActiveState() is a method on ActiveStateElements only, not to ENAEPToolbarElement. So I'm trying to make the code more testable and was trying to pass in the dependencies through the constructor. That way, I can control what IsElementInActiveState() returns. Rather than having the casting logic inside of the method. The cast inside of the constructor was a by product of this attempt.

Comment: Are you able to make element `IActiveState` and avoid the case completely? Where does `IsButtonInEnabledState` come from?

Comment: I'm looking into that. I think you might be on to something... IsButtonInEnabledState() comes from ENAEPToolbarElement.cs. ActiveStateElements.cs inherits from ENAEPToolbarElement.cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165094/discussion-between-nikolay-advolodkin-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 20):

Your mock is of `IActiveState`, not `ActiveStateElements`.

When you call `new Mock<IActiveState>()` it is creating some new type on the fly that implements the interface `IActiveState`.
This new type is not convertible to `ActiveStateElements`, which means the cast is gonna fail in the constructor.

You could create the mock like `var moqElement = new Mock<ActiveStateElements>()`, but I imagine that won't work. The methods on `ActiveStateElements` are likely not `virtual`, so you wouldn't be able to setup any of the methods.

The real issue is that `ActiveStateElementBehavior` says to consumers "I need something that implements `IActiveState`". And then internally it requires an instance of `ActiveStateElements`.

You should define whatever other methods that you need on `IActiveState`, and `ActiveStateElementBehavior` shouldn't have any casts or references to `ActiveStateElements`. It should only be aware of the interface `IActiveState`

Comment: Great answer and exactly on point as to what the OP did wrong.

Comment: So should I expect the ActiveStateElements.cs instead of the IActiveState in my constructor? But then you are correct that I won't be able to test it doing this: var moqElement = new Mock<ActiveStateElements>()

Comment: Suppose someone is stuck with the above codebase with the only difference being that `ActiveStateElements` is child class of `IActiveState` Interface. Can we use something else than FakeItEasy to do testing in this case?

Comment: hmm, not sure, but I think it would be tough. The pattern in the original question is notoriously difficult to unit test and mock.